# How to use smart pointers with SDL2 (SDL_RWops)?

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I want to write read savefile function with smart pointers and SDL2. I have little expirience with smart pointers and just want to ask is my code good, correct and no memory leaks.

this is my code:

```
std::shared_ptr<SDL_RWops> saveFile;
```

--

```
int GameEngine::ReadSave() {

        int Highlevel;

        //Open file for reading in binary
        saveFile = std::shared_ptr<SDL_RWops>(SDL_RWFromFile( "data/save.txt", "r" ), SDL_RWclose);

        //File does not exist
        if( saveFile.get()  == NULL ){
                printf( "Warning: Unable to open file! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                
                Highlevel = 0;

                //Create file for writing
                saveFile = std::shared_ptr<SDL_RWops>(SDL_RWFromFile( "data/save.txt", "w+" ), SDL_RWclose);

                if( saveFile.get() != NULL ){
                        printf( "New save file created!\n" );

                        //Initialize data
                        SDL_RWwrite( saveFile.get(), &Highlevel, sizeof(int), 1 );
                }
                else {
                        printf( "Error: Unable to create savefile! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                }
        }
        else{
                //Load data
                printf( "Reading save file...!\n" );

                SDL_RWread( saveFile.get(), &Highlevel, sizeof(int), 1 );
        }

        return Highlevel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to wrap the result of `SDL_RWFromFile` in a smart pointer is a good idea. I recommend a few improvements:

---

Factor out the opening-and-wrapping operations into a named function. For example:

```
auto OpenFile(const char *fname, const char *mode) {
    return std::shared_ptr<SDL_RWops>(SDL_RWFromFile(fname, mode), SDL_RWclose);
}
```

---

```
if( saveFile.get()  == NULL ){
```

Your whitespace is all messed up here; and also, you should generally treat smart pointers the same way you'd treat regular pointers. Avoid using `.get()` and `.reset()` and so on, unless you have a specific reason you need to emphasize the "object-ness" of the smart pointer. Keep it simple by writing:

```
saveFile = OpenFile("data/save.txt", "r");
if (saveFile == nullptr) {
    printf("Warning: Unable to open savefile! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    Highlevel = 0;
    saveFile = OpenFile("data/save.txt", "w+");
    if (saveFile == nullptr) {
        printf("Error: Unable to create savefile! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    } else {
        printf("New save file created!\n");
        SDL_RWwrite(saveFile.get(), &Highlevel, sizeof(Highlevel), 1);
    }
} else {
    printf("Reading save file...!\n");
    SDL_RWread(saveFile.get(), &Highlevel, sizeof(Highlevel), 1);
}
```

I notice that you are not checking the return value of [`SDL_RWread`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWread) for errors. That's not great.

Have you considered throwing an exception on failure, instead of using `printf` to report directly to the user? This would certainly streamline your code:

```
if (auto f = OpenFile("data/save.txt", "r")) {
    printf("Reading save file...\n");
    if (SDL_RWread(f.get(), &Highlevel, sizeof(Highlevel), 1) != 1) {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Save file format error: ") + SDL_GetError());
    }
} else if (auto f = OpenFile("data/save.txt", "w+")) {
    printf("Writing new save file...\n");
    Highlevel = 0;
    SDL_RWwrite(f.get(), &Highlevel, sizeof(Highlevel), 1);
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Unable to create save file: ") + SDL_GetError());
}
```

---

Finally, `shared_ptr` is overkill here because you never have more than one "owner" of the open file. You should certainly rewrite `OpenFile` to return a `unique_ptr` — a type which you can still implicitly convert to `shared_ptr` if you do ever need shared ownership of the file. See ["OpenSSL client and server from scratch, part 1"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/01/24/openssl-part-1/#work-with-smart-pointers-by-default); it's basically this:

```
struct RWCloser { void operator()(SDL_RWops *p) const { SDL_RWclose(p); } };

using UniqueRWops = std::unique_ptr<SDL_RWops, RWCloser>;

UniqueRWops OpenFile(const char *fname, const char *mode) {
    return UniqueRWops(SDL_RWFromFile(fname, mode));
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to overload `std::default_delete` for `SDL_RWops`, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283685/specialise-stddefault-delete-for-stdshared-ptr).

Comment: `std::default_delete` is not a customization point and should not be customized by the programmer. It's a library facility, like `std::less`. `std::less` _is_ the lifting of `a<b` into a functor; `std::default_delete` _is_ the lifting of `delete p` into a functor. It shall not be customized. If you want to specialize `unique_ptr<T,D>` with a custom `D`, just do that.